# How do I implement rstrip for arbitrary strings?

Tags: python

Say I have a bunch of strings, which can either end in `pineapple`, `ham`, or `grapefruit`.  What is the best way to produce a list of "stripped strings," that are exactly identical to the original strings except that if the string ended with `pineapple`, the `pineapple` would be trimmed from the end, and if the string ended with `ham`, the `ham` would be trimmed?

For example, suppose my input was

```
["I really like pineapple",
"I don't like ham or grapefruit",
"Today I ate a lot of ham",
"but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]
```

Then the output should be

```
["I really like",
"I don't like ham or grapefruit",
"Today I ate a lot of",
"but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]
```

Comment: Well, I tried googling "rstrip."  I thought of checking each string to see if it ended in "ham" or "pineapple," but in general there are lots of words I'd like to strip off, and lots of words I wouldn't like to strip off, and I don't want to write a zillion if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a job for `re`.  Just add an end-of-line anchor to the end of your expression to make it sub only at the end.

```
import re

stuff = ["I really like pineapple", "I don't like ham or grapefruit", "Today I ate a lot of ham", "but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]

[re.sub(r'(pineapple|ham)$','',s).strip() for s in stuff]
Out[7]: 
['I really like',
 "I don't like ham or grapefruit",
 'Today I ate a lot of',
 'but I also ate a lot of grapefruit']
```

(I added an extra `strip()` to clean up any leftover whitespace)

To do this with a list of arbitrary strings, it would look like:

```
re.sub(r'({})$'.format('|'.join(arbitrary_list_of_strings)),'',s)...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: L = ["I really like pineapple",
   ...: "I don't like ham or grapefruit",
   ...: "Today I ate a lot of ham",
   ...: "but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]


In [4]: suffixes = 'pineapple ham grapefruit'.split()

In [5]: for i in range(len(L)):
   ...:     while any(L[i].endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixes):
   ...:         for suffix in suffixes:
   ...:             if L[i].endswith(suffix):
   ...:                 L[i] = L[i][:-len(suffix)]
   ...:                 break
   ...:             

In [6]: L
Out[6]: 
['I really like ',
 "I don't like ham or ",
 'Today I ate a lot of ',
 'but I also ate a lot of ']
```

If you'd like to clean up that extra whitespace, you could do this:

```
In [7]: L = ["I really like pineapple",
"I don't like ham or grapefruit",
"Today I ate a lot of ham",
"but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]

In [8]: for i in range(len(L)):
    while any(L[i].endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixes):
        for suffix in suffixes:
            if L[i].endswith(suffix):
                L[i] = L[i][:-len(suffix)-1]
                break
   ...:             

In [9]: L
Out[9]: 
['I really like',
 "I don't like ham or",
 'Today I ate a lot of',
 'but I also ate a lot of']
```

Note that this will also kill any repeating occurrences of the target suffixes:

```
In [10]: L = ["I really like pineapple pineapple",
"I don't like ham or grapefruit",
"Today I ate a lot of ham",
"but I also ate a lot of grapefruit"]

In [11]: for i in range(len(L)):
    while any(L[i].endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixes):
        for suffix in suffixes:
            if L[i].endswith(suffix):
                L[i] = L[i][:-len(suffix)-1]
                break
   ....:             

In [12]: L
Out[12]: 
['I really like',
 "I don't like ham or",
 'Today I ate a lot of',
 'but I also ate a lot of']
```